# Vertical and horizontal designing of table in LaTex

Tags: tables

**Tex code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
        \centering
        \small
        \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{ |c|l|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|X|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Criteria} 
            \hline
            \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Stats}}} \\ & text & text & text & text \\
            \hline
            Respect & Stamina & Muscle & Fat & Sex appeal \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

The desired output, is what I want. But, I cannot get wise around tables in LaTeX. The second example is approximate since I drew it in Paint. But, I want stats to appear like that, and then plenty of rows and columns like that.

Comment: I wonder how you can obtain any output with something similar to the mess of code that have you posted.

Comment: Please test test document example before provide it on site! Also please clarify how mwny column your table should have: five or six? So far answer anticipated that five ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: wwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,multirow,array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-6]


\tymax=\linewidth

\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|C|L|L|L|L|}\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Criteria} \\\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \centering A & \centering B & \centering  C & D \\\hline
\multirow{10}{=}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Stats}} &
 \lipsum[1][1] & 
 \lipsum[2][1] & 
 \lipsum[3][1] & 
 \lipsum[4][1]\\\cline{2-5} 
      &  &  &  \\\cline{2-4}
      &  &     \\\cline{2-3}
      &      \\\cline{2-2}
      &      \\\cline{2-2}
      &      \\\cline{2-2}
      &      \\\cline{2-2}
      &      \\\cline{2-2}
      &      \\\cline{2-2}
      &      \\\cline{2-2}
      &      \\\cline{1-2}
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont stats }
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c, m] *{4}{X[c]}},
                     row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries},
                     cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
                     cell{1}{2} = {c=4}{},
                     cell{3}{1} = {r=4}{cmd=\rothead},
                     hline{1,2} = {2-Z}{},
                     hline{3,4} = {},
                     hline{5}   = {1-4}{},
                     hline{6}   = {1-3}{},
                     hline{Z}   = {1-2}{},
%
                     vline{1}   = {3-6}{},
                     vline{2,3} = {},
                     vline{4}   = {1-5}{},
                     vline{5}   = {1-4}{},
                     vline{6}   = {1-3}{},
                    } 
        &   Criteria        \\
        &   Respect     & Stamina   & Muscle    & Sex appeal    \\
Stats   &               &           &           &               \\
        &               &           &           &               \\
        &               &           &           &               \\
        &               &           &           &               \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c>{\NotEmpty}w{c}{18mm}*{3}{w{c}{18mm}}}[hvlines,corners]
& \Block{1-4}{Criteria} \\
& Respect & Stamina & Muscle &  Sex appeal \\
\Block{*-1}{\rotate Stats}& & \NotEmpty & \\
& \\
& \\
& \\
& \\
& \\
& \\
& \\
& \\
& \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes un under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]